# Sitecore E-Commerce Module - Discount/Promotional Codes

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce, sitecore, sitecore6

I am working on a project for which I must use Sitecore's E-Commerce Module (and Sitecore 6.5 rev. 120706 - aka 'Update 5') to create a web-store. One of the features that I am trying to implement is a generic promotional/discount code system - customer enters a code at checkout which grants a discount like 'free shipping', '20% off', etc. At the moment, I am looking for some guidance (a high-level solution, a few pseudo-ideas, some references to review, etc) as to how this can be accomplished.

**Summary:**

What I am looking for is a way to detect whether or not the user entered a promo code at a previous stage in the checkout line, and to determine what that promo code is, if they did.

**Progress Thus Far:**

I have thoroughly reviewed all of the Sitecore E-Commerce Services (SES) [documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/SEFE/SES12/Documentation.aspx), especially "SES Order Line Extension" documentation (which I believe will have to be modified/extended in order to accomplish this task).

Additionally, I have thoroughly reviewed the Sitecore Community article  [Extending Sitecore E-Commerce - Pricing](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2011/01/Extending-Sitecore-Ecommerce-Pricing.aspx) and believe that it may be a useful guide for applying a discount statically, but does not say much in the way of applying a discount dynamically.

After reviewing these documents, I have come up with the following possible high-level solution to start from:

1. I create a template to represent a promotional code, which holds all data relevant to the promotion (percent off, free shipping, code, etc).
2. I then create another template (based on the Product Search Group template) that holds a link to an item within a global "Promotional Code" items folder.
3. Next, I use the Product Search Group features of my new template to choose which products to apply the discount to.
4. In the source code for the checkout I create a class that checks if a code has been entered and, if so, somehow carry it through the rest of the checkout process. *This is where I get stuck.*

**More Details:**

- No using cookies
- No GET requests
- No changing/creating/deleting items in the Sitecore Database during the checkout process (e.g., no manipulation of fields of a discount item during checkout to signal that the discount has been applied)
- must stay within the scope of C#

**Last Notes:**

I will update this post with any more information that I find/progress that I make.

*I upgrade all answers that are relevant and detailed, thought-provoking, or otherwise useful to me and potentially useful to others, in addition to any high-level answers that serve as a feasible solution to this problem; even if your idea doesn't help me, if I think it will help someone else I will still upgrade it.*

Thanks, in advance, for all your help! :)

Comment: Someone asked how I can have a shopping cart without using cookies but the comment was deleted before I had time to respond - here is my reply: I believe that functionality is built into the module via pipelines. I have been attempting to review the code with a decompiler but, admittedly, some of it is a quite a bit more advanced in C# than I am. I believe that much of the JS files have also been compiled into DLLs, so I may not have seen all of them, but I am fairly certain that the module uses cookies for the cart. If anyone knows otherwise, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: My investigations into the DLL have shown me that the cart object is persisted in session. The storage persistence would be up to you (SQL, cookies, etc).

Comment: That's great, thanks. I'm running through that code right now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent the link to this question around my office and one of my co-workers who doesn't have a Stack Overflow account suggested this high-level solution, which I am posting on his behalf:

> If you cannot use cookies then what I would do is post the entered
>   code back to the server somehow and store it in session.
>
> You could either use an UpdatePanel control or some JS

Please note that ***THIS IS NOT MY ANSWER*** and I am still looking for more potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with another co-worker who had some experience using SES in the past and he and I managed to find a `DiscountCode` field in the `Sitecore.Ecommerce.Orders` namespace. I have not yet found any methods that actually use this field (and I know for a fact that there are none in that particular namespace), but it does demonstrate that the discount code feature is, at least in some small part, built into the module.

Because it is not in the documentation and there are no results in Google that I have found that refer to this, I am going to leave this question up, rather than delete it. I will be accepting the other answer, as it is a good solution, which we will probably be implementing unless we find more treasure in the DLLs.